# Paste features to new location in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, copy, paste

In ArcGIS Pro, when you paste an element from the clipboard, it will automatically appear at the same coordinates as the originally copied element.

Is there a way to paste a feature at the coordinates of a mouse click, rather than directly on top of the originally copied feature?